# Prove that a set is Borel(and hence Lebesgue)

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure, borel-sets

I'm trying to practice for the real-analysis final exam and I found this...Could you please help?
For $n$ $\in$ $\mathbb{N}$, define the following subsets of $\mathbb{R}$:
$$
         A_n=\begin{cases} (0,1]\cup[n,n+1) & , n-even \\
                     (0,1]\cup[n,n+2) &  ,n-odd
       \end{cases}
$$
Justify why $A_n$ is Borel and find $\lim_{x \to +\infty} \lambda(A_n).$
I was thinking that we could write these intervals as unions of open intervals and, being countable, they are Borel, but I'm not sure if this is correct...Also, I think that the result of the limit is 2 in the first case and 3 in the last one?

Comment: These sets are not countable, since they are real intervals. They are also not unions of open sets, since they are not open, which unions of open sets are. But you can show that $(0,1]$ and $[n,n+1),~[n,n+2)$ are Borel , and then the union of two of these will also be Borel. And the limit does not exist. These are not two sequences of sets but one, and the measure then alternates between 2 and 3, so it does not converge.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos I thought that $(0,1]\cup[n,n+1)$ could be written as $(0,1)\cup\{1\}\cup(n,n+1)\cup\{n\}$, and in this case they are not open?

Comment: Or better I could say that it is the union between an open interval and a finite one, right? So then it is Borel...

Comment: No, neither $(0,1]$ nor $[n,n+1/2)$ are open *or* finite. They are both uncountable and neither open, nor closed.

Comment: So then what's the way of proving that these intervals are Borel?

Comment: For $(0,1]$, show that $(1,\infty)$ is Borel. Then so is $(-\infty,1]$. Then $(0,1]$ is the intersection of the Borel sets $(0,1+a)$ and $(-\infty,1]$ for some $a>0$, and thus Borel. The argument for $[n,n+1)$ and $[n,n+2)$ is similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All intervals are Borel sets and unions of two Borel sets are Borel. Hence each $A_n$ is Borel . As far as $\lim \lambda (A_n)$ is concerned the limit does not exist since there are two limit points $2%$ and $3$.